# How to FTP a PDF file to a website server

Tags: shell, pdf, ftp, server

I'm currently using Sikuli to upload a PDF file to a website server. This seems inefficient. Ideally I would like to run a shell script and get it to upload this file on a certain day/time (i.e Sunday at 5AM) without the use of Sikuli.

I'm currently running Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.1 and the FileZilla FTP Client.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I have a shell script that will run a Sikuli program. This program manually enters the server hostname and password. I don't like this way because it physically takes over my computer. Whereas, I'd like to write a shell program that will FTP the file on a set schedule.

Comment: Have you tried writing a shell program yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/279176/ftp-uploading-in-bash-script) question. Also look at this cron job [howto](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-osx-yosemite.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bash file like this *(replace all [variables] with actual values)*:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd [source directory]
ftp -n [destination host]<<END
user [user] [password]
put [source file]
quit
END
```

Name it something like `upload_pdf_to_server.sh`

Make sure it has right permission to be executed:

```
chmod +x upload_pdf_to_server.sh
```

Set a cron job based on your need to execute the file periodically using command `crontab -e`

```
0 5 * * * /path/to/script/upload_pdf_to_server.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

*(This one will execute the bash file every day at 5AM)*

- [How to set cronjob](http://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/)
- [Cronjob generator](http://crontab-generator.org/)

Comment: I'm getting a 550 Permission denied error, which I believe is cause by the FTP client. I've done the "chmod +x" step. Not sure why this is coming up.

Comment: chmod +x command is different thing, The 550 error means that you do not have access rights to transfer (download/upload) the file.  this link maybe helps: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=833829

Comment: Thank you! It was a matter of being within the right directory once I was in the FTP server.